# Get the corresponding TextView of a TextBuffer

Tags: python, pygtk

I have the following problem, you may help me with:

There exists a GUI, that was created with Glade. The window contains multiple items of the type Gtk.TextView.

My intention is to change the background color of one of these items after clicking on it. Each item is connected with a signal, that is fired to change the color.

The change of the color works fine, because what i get over the widget argument is the expected Gtk.TextView.

The next step I do, is saving the name of the widget gained through get_name() into a label for later use, because as soon as I click on another item the last one should be reset to the former color. Unfortunately, when I want to get this (former) item - using get_object()-Method from Gtk.Builder and saved name as parameter - I get an object of type Gtk.TextBuffer. Now, there is the problem that TextBuffer has no modify_bg/base facility - and no option to change the color.

Is there any way to trace back a TextBuffer's TextView?

Thanks in advance!

Regards

Comment: A `textbuffer` is just a kind of data storage, its only task is to store text (and attributes). So, a textbuffer can provide data for many `textviews`, but doesn't know about them. (if you really want to know which textview uses a textbuffer, you could scan over all textviews in your project, and ask them which buffer they use)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The way you describe here is exactly how I solved this problem on my own, eventually. It's not a very clean method, but anyway ...

Comment: When using Python, it's probably more efficient and more elegant to add a list as a property to the textbuffer, which maintains a list of textviews using it.